# How to add 5 to every number of an array with Bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to create an array of user inputs and then add to each element in the array:

```
read number
for i in 1 2 3
  read array[$i]
done
let position=0
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   let array[position]+=($i+$number)
   let "position++"
done
for (( i=0; $i<3; i=$1+1 ))
do 
   echo ${array[$1]}
```

So, the user will enter "5" for number and then three more numbers for the `array(90, 80, 70)`. The results should be `array(95, 85, 75)`, but the output I'm getting is `array(95, 175, 155)`.

Comment: `let` exists only for backwards compatibility -- it shouldn't be used in new code. See discussion in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: That said, there are two immediate problems. One is the off-by-one indexing error: You're assigning to positions 1, 2 and 3 the first time, but then using 0, 1 and 2 later on account of initializing `position` to `0`. Another is the use of `array[position]+=($i+$number)` where `+=` adds to the *existing value of* `array[position]`; the off-by-one error is why this messes up your last two values and not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A saner way to write this would be:

```
read -r number
read -r -a array

for idx in "${!array[@]}"; do
  (( array[$idx] += number ))
done

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

- Instead of *assuming* that the indexes start at 0 (which they didn't, originally, because you were explicitly assigning to positions 1, 2 and 3), using `"${!array[@]}"` finds the *actual* indexes, and thus works correctly even with sparse arrays or ones not indexed starting at position 0.
- Instead of duplicating `$i` (aka the values from your array) on the right-hand side of `+=`, it only adds the `number` itself.
- Instead of iterating over indexes (again) to print the values, it just asks the array to dump *all* its values in index order with `"${array[@]}"`.

See this in operation at https://ideone.com/WTLJSu

There *is* a behavioral difference insofar as it expects all the array values to be passed on a single line of input.  If you don't want that, see the version at https://ideone.com/3OQtt3 instead.